# how does form authentication work in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to start learning Form Authentication in ASP.NET?

Comment: you need to be more specific. please elaborate.

Answer (score 7):

You might need to get a good base by following through this excellent [series](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials) of tutorials.

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to ASP.NET amigo. Refer to the following links:

[Explained: Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)

[An Overview of Forms Authentication](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb)

You can watch this video too:
[Using Basic Forms Authentication in ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/security/videos/using-basic-forms-authentication-in-aspnet)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different things that work together.

Here's a few things from my memory:

The forms authentication provider implements a default connection to a sql express db that can hold users and passwords.

The machine.config defines defaults.

The web.config in the website define overrides to machine.config like the path to redirect for the login page and number max number of login attempts.

The specialized server controls like asp:LoginView help realize the basic scenarios surrounding a website with a public portion and a members only (i.e. authenticated users) portion.

The API  exposed to code behind logic lets you do things like programatically check if a user is authenticated.